This Hispanic tv movie that aired on PBS in early 2000
This aired in early 2000 on PBS. It seemed like a 90s movie.
Here's what I remember.
A family moves from Purto Rico (or Cuba) to America (maybe New York). For some reason their father stays behind.  In the family is the mother, a teenage girl and maybe couple other kids.  
Few scenes that stick out.

The teenage girl is in a library looking for a book. Then I guess when she gets home, her mother gives her a gift of a book (could have been an English dictionary).
The mother meets another Hispanic man. He kind of reminded me of Antonio Banderas.  The man ends of dying in a bathroom/kitchen floor. The teen girl runs to the factory where her mother works at.
The teen girl does meet a Hispanic boy she liked in the neighborhood.

Can anyone tell me the name of this movie?

Oh wow, I found it.  It's called Almost a Woman.

You're allowed to answer your own questions. Please put it up as an answer and accept it to close the question.

The movie is called "Almost a Woman" (2002).

A young woman named Esmeralda and her family move to New York from a rural area of Puerto Rico. The transition is difficult due to the many challenges she and her family face.


Can you please provide one or more sources for your answer?

Well, he asked the question, so it might seem redundant. I'll add it for him.

Don't forget to accept this answer in order to mark the question as solved.
